# "if else statement" in android studio java the button to go to another activity can't run

Tags: java, android, if-statement, button, android-intent

I'm going to make a differentiated instruction module, so I need a button that categorizes levels into each material, such as values 0 to 33 in the low class, 34 - 67 in the medium class, 68 - 100 in the high class.
it will be classified when clicking the button, but when I run my code, the if else statement doesn't run, and there is no error message, I hope someone understands and can help me.

this the code in scoreActivity

```
public void btn_learn(View view) {
    TextView hasil = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hasil);
    String hasil1 = hasil.getText().toString();
    int hasil2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(hasil1));
    if (hasil2 >0 && hasil2 <= 33) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ScoreActivity.this, HomeMateriLow.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else if (hasil2 > 33 && hasil2 <= 67) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ScoreActivity.this, HomeMateriMedium.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ScoreActivity.this, HomeMateriHigh.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

          <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_learn"
            android:onClick="btn_learn"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/kuning"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_ijo"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="Learn"/>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: How is `btn_learn` called? Is it connected to any button?

Comment: Post the code, and where are you calling the btn_learn method?

Comment: btn_learn from Score.xml is called to the java class, the button is the one that directs to if else which can classify into 3 levels according to the score

Comment: place a break point at the start of function btn_learn .  Run the app on debug mode then click the btn_learn button in emulator to debug the issue

Comment: the error in logcat says that if I parse the string to integer incorrectly, it says there is a number format excepted. but I know where to fix it

`int hasil2 = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(hasil1));`

Comment: You should set `android:inputType="number"`on `hasil` in the XML file.

Comment: solved, that i called the oher variable with string inside.